# What is the difference between starting tests using ReSharper and MSTest?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, mstest

I have standard MSTest project in VS2010, .Net4. I can run tests by Test->Run... or by ReSharper->Unit Tests->Run Unit Tests.

There must be some different because tests passes only in ReSharper. I'm writing tests for class that uses Office Interop Excel.

ReShrper has default settings, VS also.

What is the basic difference between them?

Comment: Do you use a testsettings file with MSTest?

Comment: @faceman Yes, `Local.testsettings` in Solution Items (added automatically when creating Test Project). ReSharper uses that file because I have couple `DeploymantItems` and they are deployed (like when MSTest). Test are run locally.

Comment: _Resharper uses that file_ that would have been my next question. The items get deployed with both test runners?

Comment: @faceman It is not problem with deployed items, everything is copied (xlsm, nlog.config) etc. Just when test invokes creation of `Interop.Excel.Application` object then test stops (when Debug) or I have timeout when test runs without Debug. In normal runtime code everything runs without problem of course.

Comment: Does a single test run successfully? Do you have some clean up logic after each test?

Comment: @faceman I have `[ClassInitialize]` and `[ClassCleanup]` methods that, when test runs (by ReSharper), they do their job. On MSTest, first test breakes execution and return to IDE. I have only one test in that class.